# about phaser viewports and cameras

Tags: phaser-framework

Hello for 2 years now I have been developing games mostly using Java`s and libGDX or/and openGL, but now im very interested in Phaser for web-based game development and I think that is a very powerful tool.

I have no problems with game logic but when i come up with render logic in Phaser I need to know if there are possibilities for:

1 Pixel to World unit conversion.

ex: In libGDX I can work in 8x6 world units game instead of using pixels units (640*360 for exmaple) , that helps me to write a lot better logic

2 Multiple cameras in the same scene 1 camera for game and more than one for the HUD .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's been a while since I've worked with libGDX, but I think probably [the scale manager](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.ScaleManager.html) comes the closest to what you're looking for.

There's a number of tutorials covering how to use it, for example [How to Scale a Game for All Device Sizes in Phaser](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-scale-a-game-for-all-device-sizes-in-phaser/)

2. Last I heard Phaser 3 was going to have support for multiple cameras, but at this point there's a [single camera](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Camera.html#id) per game. There are ways to do this in Phaser 2.x however, for example this [phaser-cameras-example project](https://github.com/MikauSchekzen/phaser-cameras-example).

Depending upon what your HUD needs to do, however, there might be a more 'Phaser' way to do it.